# How to solve the differential equation $dx/dy = x^2 y\,$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

How to solve?

I have gotten
$$ 
y\,dy = \frac{dx}{x^2} 
$$
then taking integrals
$$ 
\int y\, dy = \int \frac{dx}{x^2} 
$$
and solving:
$$ 
y = \sqrt{-2x^{-1} + C} 
$$
but it's not the correct answer.

Comment: Why not? (apart from a $\pm$ missing)

Comment: You're missing a ")" as well. Maybe check the "correct answer" is actually correct? (Textbooks have typos!) You can just differentiate their answer. If you're not sure, post the "correct answer" with the question.

Comment: There are more ways to write the answer. For example, from $y^2/2=-x^{-1}+C$ we have $x=2/(c-y^2)$, where $c$ is another constant.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is actually correct. Even if it does not cover all solutions. We can even prove it in different ways.

**Proof $1$**

The easiest way to prove it would be to take the reciprocal of your differential equation and substitute your solution into that reciprocal. If both sides of the equation are equal, your solution is correct:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} &= x^{2} \cdot y \quad\mid\quad \left( \cdot \right)^{-1}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} &= \frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot y}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}x} &= \frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot y} \quad\mid\quad y := \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}\sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}}{\operatorname{d}x} &= \frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C} \cdot x^{2}} &= \frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}}\\
\frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}} &= \frac{1}{x^{2} \cdot \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}} \qquad \square\\
\end{align*}
$$

$\text{LHS} = \text{RHS}$ so your solution is correct. *Note that you can check the derivative [here](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=%5Csqrt%7B-2%20%5Ccdot%20x%5E%7B-1%7D%20%2B%20C%7D) step-by-step.*

**Proof $2$**

If you don't want to bother taking the derivative of the fraction from proof $1$, you can change your solution to $x$ and put that back in your DE:
$$
\begin{align*}
y &= \sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C} \quad\mid\quad \left( \cdot \right)^{2}\\
y^{2} &= -2 \cdot x^{-1} + C \quad\mid\quad -C\\
y^{2} - C &= -2 \cdot x^{-1} \quad\mid\quad \div \left( -2 \right)\\
-\frac{y^{2} - C}{2} &= x^{-1} \quad\mid\quad \div \left( \cdot \right)^{-1}\\
-\frac{2}{y^{2} - C} &= x\\
\end{align*}
$$

aka

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} &= x^{2} \cdot y \quad\mid\quad -\frac{2}{y^{2} - C} =: x\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}-\frac{2}{y^{2} - C}}{\operatorname{d}y} &= \left( -\frac{2}{y^{2} - C} \right)^{2} \cdot y\\
\dfrac{4 \cdot y}{\left( y^{2} - C \right)^{2}} &= \left( -\frac{2}{y^{2} - C} \right)^{2} \cdot y\\
\frac{4 \cdot y}{\left(y^{2} - C\right)^{2}} &= \frac{\left( -2 \right)^{2}}{\left( y^{2} - C \right)^{2}} \cdot y\\
\frac{4 \cdot y}{\left(y^{2} - C\right)^{2}} &= \frac{4}{\left( y^{2} - C \right)^{2}} \cdot y\\
\frac{4 \cdot y}{\left(y^{2} - C\right)^{2}} &= \frac{4 \cdot y}{\left( y^{2} - C \right)^{2}} \qquad \square\\
\end{align*}
$$

$\text{LHS} = \text{RHS}$ so your solution is correct. *Note that you can check the derivative [here](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=-%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7By%5E%7B2%7D%20-%20C%7D&diffvar=y) step-by-step.*

**Lost Solutions**

You have lost solutions because you forgot the $\pm$ sign when rooting with the radiant $2$. It would be correct/complete:
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
y &= \pm\sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C}\\
\end{align*}
$}$$

The complere derivation:
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{\operatorname{d}y} &= x^{2} \cdot y \quad\mid\quad \cdot \left( \operatorname{d}y \cdot x^{2} \right)\\
\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{x^{2}} &= y\, \operatorname{d}y \quad\mid\quad \cdot \int\\
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}y &= \int y\, \operatorname{d}y\\
-\frac{1}{x} + C_{1} &= \frac{1}{2} \cdot y^{2} \quad\mid\quad \cdot 2\\
\int \frac{1}{x^{2}}\, \operatorname{d}y &= \int y\, \operatorname{d}y\\
-\frac{2}{x} + 2 \cdot C_{1} &= y^{2}\\
-\frac{2}{x} + C &= y^{2} \quad\mid\quad \pm\sqrt{\cdot}\\
\pm\sqrt{-\frac{2}{x} + C} &= y\\
\pm\sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C} &= y\\
y &= \pm\sqrt{-2 \cdot x^{-1} + C} \qquad \text{q.e.d.}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Depending on which side of the equation you placed the $C_{1}$ on, the calculation effort can increase or lead to a more complicated solution formula without simplification. The equation can also be written differently, which potentially makes other formulas that are also the same solution look different.